# NDK: Native method not found

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I'm using Android NDK for the first time. What I want is to get a string from a native C++ method and use it as text in a textview. I have no idea where is the problem..

**My code**

Java:
package: package com.example.nativetest;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();

    this.textView.setText(stringFromJNI());
}

public native String stringFromJNI();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("CascadeClassifier");
    }
```

C++:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

extern "C" {
      JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL

      Java_com_example_nativetest_MainActivity_stringFromJNI
      (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
      {
            return env->NewStringUTF("Hello from C++ over JNI!");
      }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
11-24 22:41:58.646: E/AndroidRuntime(12950): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 22:41:58.646: E/AndroidRuntime(12950): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.example.nativetest.MainActivity.stringFromJNI:()Ljava/lang/String;
11-24 22:41:58.646: E/AndroidRuntime(12950):    at com.example.nativetest.MainActivity.stringFromJNI(Native Method)
11-24 22:41:58.646: E/AndroidRuntime(12950):    at com.example.nativetest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
11-24 22:41:58.646: E/AndroidRuntime(12950):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-24 22:41:58.646: E/AndroidRuntime(12950):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-24 22:41:58.646: E/AndroidRuntime(12950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
11-24 22:41:58.646: E/AndroidRuntime(12950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
11-24 22:41:58.646: E/AndroidRuntime(12950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
11-24 22:41:58.646: E/AndroidRuntime(12950):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
11-24 22:41:58.646: E/AndroidRuntime(12950):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-24 22:41:58.646: E/AndroidRuntime(12950):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-24 22:41:58.646: E/AndroidRuntime(12950):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
11-24 22:41:58.646: E/AndroidRuntime(12950):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 22:41:58.646: E/AndroidRuntime(12950):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-24 22:41:58.646: E/AndroidRuntime(12950):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
11-24 22:41:58.646: E/AndroidRuntime(12950):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
11-24 22:41:58.646: E/AndroidRuntime(12950):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted Eclipse but didn't work. After that I changed the name of the method, precompiled the cpp file and it worker. I have no explanation.